# Apply JQuery to a inserted cloned node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to apply [JQueryUI's DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) to a node and it is working for all pre-created nodes but when I use clone to insert new nodes I can't seem to get it apply.

Below is my function for creating new nodes.

```
function addActivity()
{
    var what=["spacer","mWith","mType","mDate","mWhere"];
    var newActivity;
    for(i=what.length;i>0;i--)
    {

        newActivity = document.getElementById(what[i-1]).cloneNode(true);
        insertAfter(document.getElementById("mWhere"),newActivity); 
    }

}
```

EDIT: and my insertAfter Function

```
function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) 
{
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}
```

And the HTML in question I am trying to clone

```
            <tr  id="mDate">
                <td>Activity Time: </td><td><input  class="dateTimeField" id="actTime" type="text" name="meetingDate[]" /></td>
            </tr>
```

I tried to run my JQuery again

```
 $(function() {
$( ".dateField" ).datepicker();
$( ".dateTimeField" ).datetimepicker();
});
```

But does not seem to effect the new node

even tried

```
onfocus="$(this).datetimepicker();"
```

no luck, any ideas?

Comment: What is the `insertAfter()` function?  Do you mean to be using a jQuery method there?  Also, if you clone a node with an id in it, you will need to change the id after cloning to make it unique again.

Comment: Let me add, it is just a function I wrote to add after a node.

Comment: Will a class application of JQuery not work without a unique ID?

Comment: You only need a unique ID if you're trying to find the object by id which you are in this `document.getElementById("mWhere")` and in this `document.getElementById(what[i-1])`.  You don't need a unique id if you're finding the object by class or tag or some other method.

Comment: Right, the insertion is fine, I appends after the first one it finds which is perfect. Its the datepicker is applying only to the nodes that existed when the page loaded and I can't get the cloned nodes to use the datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. 
Apparently, you need to strip the ID and Class from the node before applying the datepicker.

I added the following

```
        if(what[i-1]=="mDate")
        {
            $(newActivity).find('input').removeAttr('id');                  
            $(newActivity).find('input').removeAttr('class');                   
            $(newActivity).find('input').datetimepicker();
        }
```

after

```
   newActivity = document.getElementById(what[i-1]).cloneNode(true);
```

Comment: Perhaps the datePicker code adds classes to the node and when you clone the node and clone those classes, the datePicker registration code sees the classes already present so it thinks it doesn't have to do anything to hook it up.  When you remove the classes, it looks like a new object so it does it's thing.